# Condition to filter records with "in" and "and" operators

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

| ID | name | isSearchable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | true |
| 2 | bar | true |
| 3 | zar | **false** |

I've got some `ids` and I need to filter records where they have `isSearchable = true`.

This query give as result `ID = 1` because is searchable, but I would to apply the filter `isSearchable` to the entire result, not row-by-row.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (1, 3)
  AND isSearchable = true
```

So in this case I'm expecting **no-results** because both records should be in first `isSearchable` and after that, filter the ids.

I've tried experimenting with sub-query etc but the `in` operator (or the `or` operator) but I'm not able to accomplish the result.

Maybe is something really simple, but I've no ideas on how to solve.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need only ids or the full records?

Comment: Because this query is part of a sub-query, I'm going to use the result in a `and exists` so i think just the ids can be enought

Comment: You mean the result should be empty if the `isSearchable`  of one of the items in the `IN` statement is false.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Given a set of IDs all of them must be `isSearchable=true`. This query is used on some filters where you select multiple typology and all of them must be searchable (I cannot exclude them from the multi-select) for a lot of reasons :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach using a window function:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM (SELECT ID,
             MIN(isSearchable::INT) OVER() AS minSearchable
      FROM my_table
      WHERE id IN (1,3)) cte 
WHERE minSearchable = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nG85EadNhCGXFhMhqU2nvT/0).

Comment: This works perfectly, I was supposing this scenario cannot be resolvable with a simple query hehe

Comment: @Mistre83 - It can be a simple query; see my response.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the query as you would formulate the task it would be somehow as follows

```
with t2 as (
select id, name, is_searcheable
from t
where id in (1,3)
)
select * from t2
where not exists
  (select null from t2 where not is_searcheable);
```

*get the rows `1 and 3` if non of them is not searcheable* - returns now rows; for 1 and 2 returns two rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table
    WHERE id IN (1,3)
) x
WHERE isSearchable = true;
```

Think of a generic programming language:

```
jshell> Integer x;
x ==> null

jshell> if(x == 3 || x == null) System.out.println("bad");
|  Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "REPL.$JShell$11.x" is null
|        at (#2:1)

jshell> if(x == null || x == 3) System.out.println("bad");
bad
```

The filter order can completely change the results. If you explicitly write the query so that the execution plan is not open to interpretation, you're good.

Comment: Re "Also, if you just change the order of the filters, it works:" - In SQL order of conditions should never have any effect on results. Have you tried your solution?

Comment: This answer returns one record, which is an incorrect output.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the question.

Comment: If at least one record does not satisfy both requirements, you want no records at all.